# Why is socket io client side is not working?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am trying to make a video streamer to stream client camera using socket.io and flask, but my socket io seems not responding at all as it is not returning log on my console Connected..! What is the cause of this please  help thanks.
Here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
    sbuf = StringIO()
    sbuf.write(data_image)

    # decode and convert into image
    b = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data_image))
    pimg = Image.open(b)

    ## converting RGB to BGR, as opencv standards
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Process the image frame
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1]

    # base64 encode
    stringData = base64.b64encode(imgencode).decode('utf-8')
    b64_src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'
    stringData = b64_src + stringData

    # emit the frame back
    emit('response_back', stringData)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1')
```

and here is my index.html. I plan to have the response to be put on img with id image by using javascript socket io in my client side.

```
<div class = 'video'>
    <img id="image">
</div>

<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("Connected...!", socket.connected)
    });

    const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    video.width = 500; 
    video.height = 375; ;

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        })
        .catch(function (err0r) {
            console.log(err0r)
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }

    let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
    let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
    let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

    const FPS = 22;

    setInterval(() => {
        cap.read(src);

        var type = "image/png"
        var data = document.getElementById("canvasOutput").toDataURL(type);
        data = data.replace('data:' + type + ';base64,', ''); //split off junk 
        at the beginning

        socket.emit('image', data);
    }, 10000/FPS);


    socket.on('response_back', function(image){
        const image_id = document.getElementById('image');
        image_id.src = image;
    });

</script>
```

This is the only response that my flask server give. It is strange that my flask server completely stop after that get. What I expected is for the server to emit back the response but nothing happen

```
* Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 268-223-757
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2021 09:41:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: In your HTML file you need to include the socketio js file. And your video selector is different from the element. And there's a line that hasn't been commented "at the beginning".